Problems fetching contacts with expo-contacts
useEffect(() => {
    console.log("Checking current user...");
    if (auth.currentUser) {
      const uid = auth.currentUser.uid;
      fetchUserData(uid)
        .then((data) => {
          console.log("User data fetched:", data);
          setUser(data as User);
          fetchContacts();
        })
        .catch((error) => console.log("Error fetching user data:", error));
    }
  }, [auth.currentUser]);

  const fetchContacts = async () => {
    try {
      console.log("Requesting contacts permission...");
      const { status } = await Contacts.requestPermissionsAsync();
      console.log("Contacts permission status:", status);
      setPermissionStatus(status);
      if (status === "granted") {
        console.log("Fetching contacts...");
        const { data } = await Contacts.getContactsAsync({
          rawContacts: true,
        });
        console.log(`Contacts fetched: ${data.length} contacts.`);
        setContacts(data);
      } else {
        console.log("Contacts permission denied");
        setError("Contacts permission denied");
        Alert.alert("Permission Denied", "Contacts permission not granted.");
      }
    } catch (error: any) {
      console.error("Error fetching contacts:", error);
      setError(error.message);
      Alert.alert("Error", error.message);
    }(error: any) => {
      console.error("Error fetching contacts:", error);
      setError(error.message);
      Alert.alert("Error", error.message);
    }
  };

With this code, I get the following console.log:
LOG  Form submission initiated with values: {"email": "xxx.xxx@xxx.com", "password": "xxx"}
LOG  Set loading action dispatched with isLoading: true
LOG  Handling setLoading in reducer
LOG  Handling login request in reducer
LOG  Dispatching loginSuccess action...
LOG  Handling login success in reducer
LOG  Handling hideLoading in reducer
LOG  Checking current user...
LOG  User data fetched: {"consentReceiveEmailSMS": true, "email": "xxx.xxx@xxx.com", "emailVerified": true, "firstName": "aaa", "lastLoggedIn": {"nanoseconds": 960000000, "seconds": 1716267809}, "lastName": "bbb", "phoneNumber": "(ccc)ccc-cccc", "phoneNumberVerified": true, "registeredOn": "2023-09-24T18:30:41.071Z", "username": "xxx"}
LOG  Requesting contacts permission...
LOG  Contacts permission status: granted
LOG  Fetching contacts...
LOG  Contacts fetched: 857 contacts.

However, if I change to filter for specific fields, then my app crashes without any further warning messages. Here is the modified code block:
useEffect(() => {
    console.log("Checking current user...");
    if (auth.currentUser) {
      const uid = auth.currentUser.uid;
      fetchUserData(uid)
        .then((data) => {
          console.log("User data fetched:", data);
          setUser(data as User);
          fetchContacts();
        })
        .catch((error) => console.log("Error fetching user data:", error));
    }
  }, [auth.currentUser]);

  const fetchContacts = async () => {
    try {
      console.log("Requesting contacts permission...");
      const { status } = await Contacts.requestPermissionsAsync();
      console.log("Contacts permission status:", status);
      setPermissionStatus(status);
      if (status === "granted") {
        console.log("Fetching contacts...");
        const { data } = await Contacts.getContactsAsync({
          fields: [Contacts.Fields.FirstName, Contacts.Fields.LastName, Contacts.Fields.PhoneNumbers, Contacts.Fields.Emails],
        });
        console.log(`Contacts fetched: ${data.length} contacts.`);
        setContacts(data);
      } else {
        console.log("Contacts permission denied");
        setError("Contacts permission denied");
        Alert.alert("Permission Denied", "Contacts permission not granted.");
      }
    } catch (error: any) {
      console.error("Error fetching contacts:", error);
      setError(error.message);
      Alert.alert("Error", error.message);
    }(error: any) => {
      console.error("Error fetching contacts:", error);
      setError(error.message);
      Alert.alert("Error", error.message);
    }
  };

Console logs are as follows:
LOG  Checking current user...
LOG  User data fetched: {"consentReceiveEmailSMS": true, "email": "xxx.xxx@xxx.com", "emailVerified": true, "firstName": "aaa", "lastLoggedIn": {"nanoseconds": 960000000, "seconds": 1716267809}, "lastName": "bbb", "phoneNumber": "(ccc)ccc-cccc", "phoneNumberVerified": true, "registeredOn": "2023-09-24T18:30:41.071Z", "username": "xxx"}
LOG  Requesting contacts permission...
LOG  Contacts permission status: granted
LOG  Fetching contacts..

According to expo-contacts documentation, this is the right way to request these fields. My app.json looks as follows and has according to my understanding also the right permissions:
{
  "expo": {
    "plugins": [
      [
        "expo-contacts",
        {
          "contactsPermission": "Allow xxx to access your contacts."
        }
      ]
    ],
    "name": "xxx",
    "slug": "xxx",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "orientation": "portrait",
    "icon": "./assets/color_logo_with_background.png",
    "userInterfaceStyle": "light",
    "splash": {
      "image": "./assets/splash.png",
      "resizeMode": "contain",
      "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
    },
    "assetBundlePatterns": ["**/*"],
    "ios": {
      "supportsTablet": true,
      "bundleIdentifier": "com.xxx.zzz",
      "infoPlist": {
        "NSContactsUsageDescription": "xxx"
      }
    },
    "android": {
      "adaptiveIcon": {
        "foregroundImage": "./assets/adaptive-icon.png",
        "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
      },
      "permissions": ["READ_CONTACTS"]
    },
    "web": {
      "favicon": "./assets/favicon.png"
    },
    "extra": {
      "eas": {
        "projectId": "aaa"
      }
    },
    "sdkVersion": "51.0.0"
  }
}

I've added every log I can think of, but I don't know how to further debug this situation. I'm using ExpoGo.
The other thing is, that on an iPhone8, the code works without problems, on newer generations (12 and above) it doesn't. Both devices run the same iOS version (17.5.1)
Any advice is appreciated.

plus one. experiencing this issue too. i'm going to try asking the expo developers discord and see if anyone wants to chime in

@bdotsamir Do you have any update?

yes actually! So it turns out the bug is a problem with expo-contacts. It was fixed and merged into the main branch, but it has yet to be pushed out to npm. In the mean time, check out this PR thread: https://github.com/expo/expo/pull/28968
